# How to listen for new messages in a channel from scratch in Discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I wanna learn how to listen for new messages purely with requests to the Discord API. I already know how to load messages (I fetch https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/channelid/messages?limit=50), but I can't seem to figure out how to listen for new messages, and I am pretty sure that it's not in the Discord API documentation either.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I mean you could always read how [discord.js](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js) does it in their source code.

Comment: @Tyler2P I actually did try, but it's too many files interacting with each other, and it definitely does not do it in a simple and straightforward way, but in multiple big files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a library to interface with the discord API.

For NodeJS, the most common one is [discord.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js).

If you really want to do this manually, listening to messages is done via a websocket connection (they call it a Gateway connection).
The docs for this can be found here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateways

Even their own Docs say the following, though:

> The API for interacting with Gateways is complex and fairly unforgiving

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: discord.js let you build apps connected to your bots, but not to your own account. So, you can only listen to messages coming from the servers to which your bot is subscribed, which are normally your own servers. You cannot listen to messages coming from servers to which your personal account is subscribed.

Comment: There are two APIs, one for bots and another one used by the web version (and probably the desktop/mobile versions). The first one is fully supported by disocrd.js and is very well written, but if you want to build an app connected to your own account and perform just like any client, you're out of luck. All I managed to find is this module for nodejs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-client-api), which only covers the REST part of the client API, but not the websocket part.

Comment: @Vladimir Discords User and Bot APIs are actually closely related and used to be effectively identical (except for authentication). Forked versions of old libraries exist which are designed to use the User API, see for example https://github.com/aiko-chan-ai/discord.js-selfbot-v13
The term you're searching for here is Selfbots, see https://github.com/topics/discord-selfbot.
Note that automating User Accounts is against Discords TOS and they actively ban accounts which are judged to be likely automated.

Comment: @leumasme thanks and sorry, I just saw your response, I'll look into it. As a matter of fact, I don't want a big deal of automation, I just want to be able to read incoming messages on selected channels. I hope this is acceptable.

Comment: @leumasme I tested the selfbot and it works like a charm, thanks a lot!